# Est-ce que les professeurs tutoient les étudiants adultes ?

Tags: tutoiement

Je pense que les professeurs des jeunes élèves les tutoient, mais comment fait-on avec les étudiants à l'université ?

Comment: Je suis sûre qu'il n'y a pas de norme, même si je soupçonne que le vouvoiement soit plus courant. Mais je pense  qu'il peut y avoir des tendances selon les filières (je sais que les scientifiques ont le tutoiement plus facile, est-ce vrai uniquement entre pairs ou aussi entre enseignant et étudiant ?) Et il y a aussi divers types d'enseignants à l'université, en France entre le chargé de cours qui fait des TP et le professeur HDR  il y a un monde.  Et ça peut être différent dans les divers pays francophones...

Comment: En me basant sur mon expérience personnelle (Université et école d'ingénieur) je dirais qu'il n'y a pas de règle. C'est léger pour en tirer une conclusion bien sur mais j'ai vu des tutoiements et des vouvoiements dans diverses situations. A l'inverse le tutoiement des professeurs est beaucoup plus rare (mais là n'est pas pas question). A la rigueur on pourrait dire que le vouvoiement est plus courant dans les cours magistraux et le tutoiement devient plus probable dès que le nombre de personnes concernées diminue..

Comment: Enseignant à l'université, je suis d'accord avec les commentaires : il n'y a pas de règle absolue (côté scientifique en tout cas). Enormément de facteurs entrent en jeu dans le choix du professeur, de sa personnalité à la relation qu'il veut établir avec ses élèves en passant par la culture de la filière, l'âge des personnes en jeu... Pour l'anecdote, je tutoie d'habitude les élèves, mais le jour où s'est retrouvé dans ma classe quelqu'un de plus de deux fois mon âge, je me suis retrouvée sans savoir comment m'adresser à lui... Ces usages sont sources de débats inépuisables entre enseignants.

Comment: Je ne veux pas faire la rabat-joie mais cette question n'est pas strictement reliée à la langue française mais plutôt à la culture française (je sais bien que les deux sont reliés mais..)

Answer (score 5):

Cela dépend vraiment des universités et des professeurs mais la tendance est plutôt à vouvoyer des élèves adultes.

Nous dirons plutôt qu'on ne prend pas de risque à vouvoyer un élève majeur. Même si les étudiants (j'en suis un) ne sont pas "choqués" quand un professeur les tutoie.

Answer (score 2):

La politesse académique européenne demande la forme de politesse, donc le vouvoiement mutuel en français.

Je n'ai jamais vu un Professeur (d'université) ou un enseignant de classes préparatoires tutoyer un étudiant. Le Professeur est souvent comparable à un manager de sa chaire ou de son institut. En université, j'ai parfois pratiqué et vu pratiquer le vouvoiement d'étudiant à étudiant lors de prises de parole devant tout l'amphi ou devant plusieurs profs (pour ne pas créer de décalage plus que par respect de l'étiquette).

Mais les enseignants et surtout les chargés de TD en université (postdoc et autres) tutoient beaucoup plus facilement les étudiants, je dirais même que c'est la règle d'établir le tutoiement après la première rencontre, ou au sein des chaires ou des facultés.

Mais le tutoiement s'établissant la plupart du temps de personne à personne,  c'est comme toujours à la personne en position d'autorité ou la plus haute dans la hiérarchie sociale traditionnelle (du plus âgé au plus jeune, de la femme à l'homme) de proposer le tutoiement.

Comment: Ça doit dépendre des disciplines et des lieux. En sciences (maths/physique/info), en France, je n'ai jamais vu un étudiant en vouvoyer un autre. La plupart des professeurs vouvoient, mais il y en a qui tutoient, et ce n'est pas impoli. Le seul point sur lequel je suis d'accord est que c'est à l'enseignant de choisir.

Answer (score 1):

Le tutoiement dépend aussi de la culture; en France, on a tendance à tutoier seulement nos amis proches ou notre famille, tandis qu'au Québec le tutoiement est utilisé beaucoup plus généralement (un marchant va tutoier sa clientèle, un patron va tutoier son employé, etc).

À l'université, les professeurs québécois demandent souvent d'être appelés par leur premier nom, et vont également tutoier leurs étudiants. Cela dépend évidemment de la préférence de l'individu, certains préfèrent être familier avec leurs étudiants (tutoiement), et d'autres voudront au contraire mettre l'emphase sur la différence de status.

Comment: Je chante dans un chorale: mon voisin m'y a dit qu'il m'y faut tutoyer tout le monde (dans la chorale), et que de faire ansi est plutot la norme en Bretagne et en Normandie.